# hook_field_prepare_view not called

Tags: entities, hooks

If I understand correctly, hook_field_prepare_view should be called each time, when some field value is displayed.
But when I visit some node page, that contains some fields, my hook_field_prepare_view is not called. I have simple hook implementation as follows:

```
function mymodule_field_prepare_view($entity_type, $entities, $field, $instances, $langcode, &$items) {
watchdog('mymodule', 'field');
}
```

I have no record 'field' in log messages, so I think my function is not called. I flushed caches several times. 
Could anybody help, where can be problem?

Comment: Field hooks are mostly only invoked for the module that implements the field. If you're trying to prepare the view for a field you've defined yourself in `hook_field_info()`, then this would be the correct hook to use. If you're trying to alter the view of a field defined by another module, I think you'll need to find a different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documentation says:

> This hook is invoked before the field values are handed to formatters for display

It will not be called when content is served from cache - as values are not handed anywhere, it's just output taken from cache table (or other cache bin) and sent to display.